# Is it possible to visualize Grafana’s internal statistics?

Tags: data-visualization, grafana

We are using Grafana for data visualization and would like to have some overview about what our users are doing. There is a statistics page at /admin/stats, accessible for administrators that has some numbers about active sessions, logins, dashboards, etc. Is it possible to easily access this data and visualize the numbers in a dashboard?

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using Prometheus, Grafana now exposes metrics for Prometheus on `/metrics` endpoint - included in here are the statistics you're interested in. See https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/prometheus/#getting-grafana-metrics-into-prometheus

I'm not familiar with other monitoring systems, sorry.

Hope this helps!